# What's the meaning of "system" in ecosystem?

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Ecosystem* is defined as

> a system formed by the interaction of a community of organisms with their environment.

Does *system* in this context mean sense 1 from Dictionary.com: [*an assemblage or combination of things or parts forming a complex or unitary whole?*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/system?s=t) and/or sense 1 from AHDE: [*a group of interacting, interrelated, or interdependent elements forming a complex whole*](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/system)?

Comment: Yes both those definitions are applicable.

Comment: I don't think there's much difference in those two definitions. They pretty much say the same thing: a combination (or _group_) of things (or _parts_) forming a complex whole.

Comment: What confuses me about the question is that in the definition of ecosystem it says, "a *system* *formed by* [...] *interaction* of [...] *organisms*"   And the dictionary definitions provided talk about "an assemblage (community) or combination of things (organisms) *forming* a complex whole (the ecosystem).  So OP's *real* question must have something to do with misunderstanding or not understanding some of the other terms used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED's first citation for *ecosystem* is A. G. Tansley in *Ecology (1935)* ...

> *The fundamental concept appropriate to the biome considered together with all the effective inorganic factors of its environment is the **ecosystem**, which is a particular category among the physical systems that make up the universe.*

The word *ecology* had been around at least 60 years at that time, but Tansley is regarded as [the founding figure of British ecology](http://www.newphytologist.org/contentpages/index/10), and it seems very likely he actually coined the term *ecosystem*.

For most practical purposes, *the/an ecosystem* is synonymous with *the/an ecology*. But if you had to make a distinction, it's that *ecosystem* specifically focusses on the *interacting set of components considered as a single coherent unit*, whereas *ecology* often refers to *the **study** of ecosystems*. Thus (in singular constructions *without* an article), you can say *"I study ecology"*, but not *"?I study ecosystem"*.

---

As regards OP's definitions, I'm a bit suspicious of the first one anyway. Tansley's definition clearly states that an *ecosystem* embodies both the *biome* (organic, living elements) ***and*** inorganic elements. In reality, the "environment" of an organism does in fact include *other* organisms, but I think the way the definition is worded tends to obscure that essential fact.

I can't even guess what distinction OP sees between his second and third definitions. They look the same to me (exactly as I would expect, since they're both defining the same thing).